# Can't install any NuGet Package if at least one Source is not available

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

The following problem does not exist in VS2013 (Premium),I can only reproduce it in VS2015 (Enterprise)

I've added a custom NuGet package source.
If that source if not available I cannot install **any** package (for example EntityFramework)

I get a message

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
>   'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with respect to project 'ConsoleApplication9',
>   targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
>
> Exception'System.AggregateException' thrown when trying to add source
>   'http://XXX/FeedService.svc/'.
>
> Please verify all your online package sources are available.

From the last line of the message I assume that this is not a bug but as I said it works on VS2013

Any idea why this has changed?
Can I do anything about this?

Comment: If you are on the latest version of NuGet 3.4.4 or even the 3.5 beta then I would file a bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/nuget/home/issues)

Comment: Thanks @MattWard I'm using 3.4.4.1321 ,I'll file a bug report

Comment: @GeorgeVovos Hello can you post a link to the bug report please?

Comment: @LukePuplett Here it is but it will not help you, as you can see from the answer this is by design. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2978

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. Since we support searching across multiple sources for the packages that you need, we need to be able to reach all sources and get the package results before restoring these packages, to be deterministic and consistent in the way we do restore.

However, we understand that some users go into offline/online modes and we are investing in building a feature set that will enable you to temporarily disable some sources while you are working offline. In the meantime you can look into creating a [custom nuget.config](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings) that does not contain the offending source and using that to restore when you are in the offline mode.

Comment: Is there a fix yet? I am having the same problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188620/how-do-i-uninstall-a-nuget-package-that-is-not-available

Comment: In that case, can you please rename the Cache folder under nuget to something else, perhaps, "ThisIsNotACacheCacheFolder"?

Comment: So, a year later, how are things going with that temporary disabling of sources?  My company has its own NuGet sources that I connect to through a VPN.  Because of this "design" decision, if I want to get any NuGet packages at all, I have to connect to our VPN even if I'm just doing hobby programming...or I have to go disable the company source, then re-enable it later.  This makes for a very clunky process.  What's especially irritating is that even if in the NuGet window I have a specific feed selected, it still searches all the feeds and fails if one isn't reachable.

Comment: That is interesting @Harikrishna but this means that the initial results are not consistent because listing the packages is working with the rest of the online sources.

Comment: Still an issue almost 2 years later all because i can't access a network share and i just want to use nuget.org anyway

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question so I'm surprised [the workaround](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2978#issuecomment-357283418) from the bug report wasn't added here. To save reader a click:

1. From within Visual Studio, open Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package
   Manager -> Package Sources
2. Untick all of the package sources that are unavailable, leaving just
   the public NuGet entries.
   [image: NuGetExample]
3. Install your packages as normal

Once you're back in your office follow steps 1 and 2 again but this time make sure everything is checked.

Comment: Malice, people with multiple Package Sources probably know about this (thanks though), the thing is we don't want to do that all the time...