# How do I uninstall a nuget package that is not available?

Tags: nuget

I have moved my project to a new machine and do not have access to an old nuget package called SBD.Common that was stored locally on the old machine.

I want to uninstall the package from the project 
When I use Manage Nuget Packages for solution I can see that the package is installed but not available in this source.

When I click the Uninstall button I get an error

```
An error occured while trying to restore the packages" Unable to find version '1.0.0' of 'SBD.Common'

c:\Program files(x86)\Microsoft SDKS\NugetPackages\:Package 'SBD.Common.1.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\' 
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json:Package 'SBD.Common.1.0.0' is not found
```

How do I tell my project that I don't want to restore this package without gaining access to the package?

Here is my Nuget.Config at C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\NuGet

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft and .NET" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="False" />
    <add key="automatic" value="False" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
</configuration>
```

I am using Nuget version 3.4.4.1321

Comment: For packages that just add references to the project, you could remove the reference manually and locate and delete the entry of the package in the packages.config file.

Comment: I have no packages.config file in the project, and I also don't have a reference to the dll in the project

Comment: It turned out that my build had another error due to a missing reference.  When I corrected the other error the Nuget errors dissapeared.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830799/cant-install-any-nuget-package-if-at-least-one-source-is-not-available

Comment: Adding a new NuGet.Config to the project is a work around but I don't understand why the issue is happening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the problem was that I had the files listed in packages.config

Comment: Yep, by just deleting the reference in your solution's packages.config file, then you can just right-click on the reference (in the Solution window) and delete the package.