# Is there a way to configure NuGet to ignore unavailable package sources?

Tags: nuget

When developing in Visual Studio 2017, I use a combination of the standard NuGet package source, and package sources from the company I work for.

To access those company package sources, I have to connect to our company VPN.

Unfortunately, this means I have to *always* be connected to our company VPN, no matter what I'm developing, because otherwise NuGet gives me this:

> Exception 'System.AggregateException' thrown when trying to add source 'http://[one of my company's package sources]'. Please verify all your online package sources are available.
>   One or more errors occurred.
>   Unable to load the service index for source http://[one of my company's package sources].
>   An error occurred while sending the request.
>   The remote name could not be resolved: '[one of my company's package sources]'

This would make sense if I'm trying to use a package only hosted on my company's servers.  But even if I specifically set the Package source dropdown to nuget.org, I get this error.

There's an issue to fix it, but it's two years old and shows no signs of activity:  [install fails when a nuget Source is unavailable even when this is not the selected Source #2614](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2614)

So, is there a way somehow to configure NuGet to ignore missing package sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to config NuGet to ignore some sources.

If you have all your non-company code in a single folder structure, then in the root you can put a `nuget.config` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="My Company's NuGet Source" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
</configuration>
```

If you're not sure what that key should be, run `nuget sources` from the command line:

```
>nuget sources
Registered Sources:

  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  2.  My Company's NuGet Source [Disabled]
      https://path/to/the/nuget
  3.  Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [Enabled]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

This is also a good way to verify that the `nuget.config` is being detected.  The `Disabled` is from my `nuget.config` file; if I run `nuget sources` in my company code folder, number 2 shows as `Enabled`.

You can find full details about the structure of `nuget.config` here:

[nuget.config reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)

Answer (score 3):

As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37851006/2792414), the behavior of Visual Studio 2017 is by design, but maybe you can use a custom nuget.config as a workaround (also explained in that answer).