# Stop Moq NuGet package searching for source

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, moq, .net-4.8

I am currently using Moq 4.20.70 (latest version as of writing) in a c# .NET Framework 4.8 unit test project from a NuGet package in VS 2019 16.11.34 Pro, however every time I debug it is searching for its source which I don't have (or want) with dozens of popups for each file its searching for which is incredibly irritating. Is there any way to stop this?

I have 'Enable Just My Code' ticked and I don't have this problem for any other package. I realise I can can enable 'Enable Source Link support' but I don't want to be stepping through the Moq library source itself every time I debug a test. Here is an example:

[image: Moq source not found]

To trigger this I just need to change the execution point in the source.

Comment: Hi,@Symo. You could try to see if the solutions in [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930747/excluding-files-from-nuget-package-while-including-all) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151156/is-there-a-way-to-configure-nuget-to-ignore-unavailable-package-sources)  are helpful to you.